# yii validate an input array of phone numbers

Tags: php, jquery, validation, yii

I'm working on a multiple contact form in Yii 1.1.16. Where the user can add multiple phone numbers.

Problem is, how would i validate this using Yii's `rules()`?

```
<div class="form-group">
                <?php 
                echo $form->labelEx($model,'contacts', array('class'=>'col-md-3 control-label')); 
                ?>
                  <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="multiple-contact multiple-form-group input-group padding-bottom-10px" data-max="5">
                            <div class="input-group-btn input-group-select">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span class="concept">Phone</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#phone">Phone</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#fax">Fax</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#mobile">Mobile</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contacts',array('type'=>'text', 'class'=>'input-group-select-val', 'name'=>'contacts[type][]','value'=>'phone')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contacts',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255, 'name'=>'contacts[value][]','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                            <?php echo $form->error($model,'contacts'); ?>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            </span>
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

i tried using this, but doesn't work

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
    array('contacts[value][]', 'required'),
    array('contacts[value][]', 'integerOnly'=>true),
    array('contacts[value][]','type','type'=>'array','allowEmpty'=>false)
    );
}
```

Here is a sample [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c6fqyg6/) on how the jQuery side works. I want it to be able to validate with `'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,`. Also, when more fields are added, it duplicates the `id` of the input. and no ajax post is done `onblur/onfocus`

Comment: How are you saving them in your database? Are they seperate records in another table?

Comment: will save them in a different table. just not sure how to validate them in Yii.

Comment: @user3535256 it must be an int, and required

Answer (score 5):

Use custom validation.

Declare a custom validator in your rules, and define the validation you require in the validator method.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
      array('contacts', validateContacts),
    );
}

public function validateContacts($attribute,$params)
{
   if (length($this->contacts) == 0) {
      $this->addError($attribute, 'You must add at least one contact!');
   }
   foreach($this->contacts as $contact) {
      // ...
   }

}
```

In your controller, assign the contacts array to the Model field and call the model's validation method. If there are any errors it will display through the line

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'contacts'); ?>
```

in the view.

The controller contains the code to invoke the validation.

```
$contactModel = new Contact;
// assign the array of contacts to the model
$contactModel->contacts = $POST['myForm]['contacts']
$contactsModel->validate();

$this->render('myform', contactModel);
```

If you want the validation to happen through Ajax, you need to specify so when creating your form:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'top-websites-cr-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
   'clientOptions' => array(
      'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
      'validateOnChange'=>true),
));
```

In this case your controller can check for ajax forms.

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='branch-form')
{
   echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
   Yii::app()->end();
}
```

references:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: yeah, but how to also get it to work on client side?

Comment: I updated my answer. You were not clear that you wanted the details on the client side.

Comment: sorry about that. where is the js for validate client sided tho?

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a separate model with it's own validation.
Then in your controller you have to validate the main models and the related models separately.

Here is a good guide for such a setup:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/384/creating-and-updating-model-and-its-related-models-in-one-form-inc-image/

Comment: but how to you validate an input array in my CActiveRecord's `public function rules()`?

Comment: you no longer have to, you walk through the array and validate it's individual members.

Comment: will this way allow client side validation too?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, my guess would be that it would if you use activeTextfield

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion for best validation regarding phonenumbers you should use libphonenumber php library and there is an extension for it regarding yii framework here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/libphonenumber/

basic usage:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('libphonenumber',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.libphonenumber'));
$phonenumber=new libphonenumber\LibPhone($your_phone_number);
$phonenumber->validate();
```

for more details regarding usage and capabilities of libphonenumber php library you can find here:
https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP

Answer (score -1):

Let us consider you have a model called **ContactNo** and it looks like

```
    class ContactNo extends CFormModel
    {
        public $contact;

        public function rules()
        {
            return array(
// your rules  
                array('contact', 'required'),
                array('contact','length','min'=>2)
            );
        }

        /**
         * Declares attribute labels.
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'contact'=>'Contact No',
            );
        }
    }
```

The controller as **SiteController** and the action Name as **actionIndex**

Then your controller should look something like this

```
public function actionIndex()
        {
// set how many contact fields you want here
                $contactCount = 3;

                $models = array();

                if(isset($_POST['ContactNo']))
                {
                    $successModels = 0;
                    foreach($_POST['ContactNo'] as $key=>$value)
                    {
                        $model = new ContactNo;
                        $model->attributes = $value;

                        if($model->validate()) // this validates your model
                            $successModels++; // it tells how many contact No.s have been validated

                        $models[$key]=$model;
                    }

// if all the contact nos are validated, then perform your task here
                    if($successModels === $contactCount)
                    {
                        // save your models
                        echo 'models saved';
                        Yii::app()->end();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for($index = 0;$index < $contactCount; $index++)
                    $models[] =  new ContactNo;
                }

                $params = array();

                $params['contactCount']=$contactCount;
                $params['models']= $models;

                $this->render('index',$params);
        }
```

**Now lets Go to view.** Obviously the view is **index.php** and it will be something like

```
// Include all the initial part required for activeforms

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($models); ?>

            <?php foreach ($models as $index=>$model): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,"[{$index}]contact"); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[{$index}]contact",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,"[{$index}]contact"); ?>
        </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

// Include the submit button
```

**Hope this helps you or might give you an idea atleast to achieve your goal.**